# Is there a vimari or vimium port for safari on mojave?

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, safari-extensions, open-source

I loved [vimari](https://github.com/guyht/vimari) but the Mojave update made it no longer work because of the stronger permissions system.  Is there any way to install this safely, or barring that make extensions work again?

Comment: Yes, Vimari is now available on the Mac App Store. I guess it the devs a while to update the code base to make it work with the App Store, and then it took Apple a while longer to approve it. 

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vimari/id1480933944

Unfortunately, it seems to be the only option, for now. Fortunately, it works well.

Comment: Vimari now is available in Mac App Store and works.

Answer (score 1):

`vimari` currently has a somewhat experimental process to compile and install it locally for Safari 12, detailed here:

https://github.com/guyht/vimari/blob/master/docs/safari_12.md

> **Note: We are currently working on improving this installation flow, as well as the extension itself. Because vimari now has to be released
>   as a *Safari  App Extension* instead of a *Safari Extension* it
>   requires some fundamental changes to the code. We can't guarantee that
>   all the features work in  this version. It's a learning process for us
>   so bare with us.**
>
> 1. Clone this repo
>
>    ```sh
>    $ git clone git@github.com:guyht/vimari.git
>    ```
> 2. Open the Swift project located at `app_extension/vimari` in Xcode
> 3. Configure the Signing settings for both the `vimari` and `extension` targets    to use your information rather than the Vimari
>      team's (see [this SO
>      answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754341/none-of-your-accounts-are-a-member-code-signing-errors-after-upgrading-to-xcode)
>      for more information).
> 4. If you want different settings than the default ones, make your changes in    `settings.js`. You can always come back later to change
>      the settings again.
> 5. Build and run the project (`⌘ + r`)
> 6. An empty GUI box will show up - ignore it (we'll fix it later). Go to    Safari and open up settings (`⌘ + ,`). Go to *Extensions* and
>      you should    see **vimari** in the list of extensions. Enable it.
> 7. You may now press stop in Xcode and close Xcode. The extension will be    available even if you restart Safari.
>
> This was tested on High Sierra with Safari Technology Preview (version
>   12). Let  us know if something is not working for you.

Answer (score -1):

I am working on Vimac, which is Vimium but for macOS. It supports Safari.

Check out the demo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WwZtN8_7Tc

You can try out the beta here:

https://vimacapp.com/